# Animation before leave the page JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have some content on the page which appears when page is loading :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#1").show(function(){
     $("#2").slideDown(function(){
     });    
   });
});
```

I was wondering if there is a chance to to the same thing but before leave the page.

Comment: You can't. You can only trigger a dialog.

See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( window ).unload(function() {
}

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

unload event is fired by many cases, i would suggest to test thoroughly.

I too will prefer not to do such things when user wants to leave page, not good UI practice unless its a necessary requirement.

make sure the loaded resources of the page are still resent otherwise Leeds to exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, as it would allow you to prevent the user from leaving the page. You probably would not want a website that did not allow you to close it when you wanted to, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only trigger a dialog before a page unloads.

See:

[How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no event that triggers that.

However, you can use those animations when someone clicks away to another page (using onclick). That is, navigates to another page by clicking a link/div on your current page. Then you can redirect them.